# Please suggest a better solution to an optimization puzzle

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming, memoization

Please find below a problem, its solution and its working implementation. The solution below has a time complexity of O(n!) (Please correct me if I am wrong).

## My Question:

1)Please suggest a solution with better time complexity. Given it's an optimization problem, Dynamic programming or memoization seems like a better option. Also please provide an analysis justifying the time complexity of your solution. Thanks!

## Problem:

A pipe company produces pipes of fixed length n. It gets orders of k number of pipes each with length between (0,n] every day. Write an algorithm that will help the company fulfill the orders using minimum number of fixed length of pipes.

## Solution1:

For k orders, consider all permutations. For each permutation, greedily compute cost. Pick permutation with minimum cost.
We need two data structures: 1) Order: use list 2) Cost: list containing all pipes used where value is the remaining length of pipe.
If we used a single pipe of length n fully, Then the data structure representing cost is [0].

```
#IMPLEMENTATION OF Solution1

import itertools
n = 10

def fulfill_element_greedily(pipes_used, order):
    eligible_pipes = filter(lambda x : x - order >= 0, pipes_used)
    if len(eligible_pipes) == 0:
        new_pipe_used = n-order
    else:
        eligible_pipes.sort(reverse=True)
        new_pipe_used = eligible_pipes[-1] - order
        pipes_used.remove(eligible_pipes[-1])
    return pipes_used + [new_pipe_used]   


def cost_for_greedy_fulfill(orders):
    pipes_used = []
    for order in orders:
        pipes_used = fulfill_element_greedily(pipes_used, order)
    return len(pipes_used)

def min_cost(orders):
    if(any(map(lambda x : x > n,orders))):
        print "Orders %s" % str(orders)
        raise ValueError("Invalid orders")
    return min(map(cost_for_greedy_fulfill,itertools.permutations(orders))) if len(orders)!=0 else 0


def test():
    assert 0 == min_cost([])
    assert 1 == min_cost([1])
    assert 1 == min_cost([5])
    assert 1 == min_cost([10])
    assert 2 == min_cost([10,2])
    assert 2 == min_cost([2,9,7])
    assert 2 == min_cost([1,7,9,3])
    return "tests passed"

print test()
```

Comment: Is this your school work?

Comment: It is a question my friend was asked during a google interview. I couldn't come up with a better solution than O(n!). I have other solutions in my mind which are slightly better than the above, but they are not orders of degrees better than the one I shared.

Comment: This is the NP-hard bin packing problem (where pipes correspond to bins and orders correspond to objects), so there is no algorithm that finds an _optimal_ solution in polynomial time.

Comment: Product pipe with fixed length n? how can it fulfill orders with length (0,n]?

Comment: @PhamTrung The company is allowed to cut its pipes into shorter ones.

Comment: @xjcl, is right. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem , its got quite a few algorithms for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Dynamic Programming algorithm of Complexity O(k*(2^k)) as follows:

define a state that contains the following 2 members:

```
struct State {
  int minPipe;      // minimum number of pipes
  int remainingLen; // remaining length of last pipe
}
```

We say state a is better than state b if and only if

```
(a.minPipe < b.minPipe) or (a.minPipe == b.minPipe && a.remainingLen > b.remainingLen)
```

The problem itself can be divided into 2^k states:

```
State states[2^k]
```

where states[i] represents the optimal state (minimum number of pipe which maximum remaining length of last pipe) that already produce pipe x, (1<=x<=k), where the x-th bit in the binary representation of i is set.

for example,

```
states[0]: inital state, no pipe produced
states[1]: optimal state with only the 1st pipe produced
states[2]: optimal state with only the 2nd pipe produced
states[3]: optimal state with the 1st and 2nd pipe produced
states[4]: optimal state with only the 3rd pipe produced
...
```

By processing all the previous state for each state x:

states[x] = best state transit from all possible previous state y, where x > y and there's only 1 bit difference between the binary representation of x and y.

The final answer is from state[2^k - 1].minPipe;

Complexity: each state has at most (k-1) previous states, there're 2^k states so the final complexity is O(k * 2^k) which is less than O(k!)